# How can I create a segue that change only view?

Tags: xcode13

I'm creating macOS app whit Xcode but when create a segue of type Show he open a new window.
i want that it change only view whit out creating new window.
i already tried all the other segue type.
I'm using:
Xcode 13.1, Swift 5.5 and Swift storyboard.

Comment: you cant do that with segues, segues are meant to navigate to new window! you need to show some code so we can see what you are trying to acheive

Comment: For now I have builded only the GUI